# Ubuntu22.04 suddenly goes black

Tags: 22.04, vmware

When I was programming with Goland, the following message suddenly appeared on the black screen：

```
bles libcrc32c nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp l1c snd_ens1371 intel_rapl_msr bnep snd_ac97_codec 
gameport ac97_bus snd_pcm intel_rapl_common overlay crct1odif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel vmw_balloon 
aesni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crypto_simd cryptd vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_tran
sport_common vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock rapl snd_rawmidi binfmt_misc snd_seq joydev input_leds s
erio_raw btusb nls_iso8859_1 btrtl btbcm btintel snd_seq_device btmtk snd_timer bluetooth snd ecdh_g
eneric ecc soundcore vmw_vmci mac_hid sch_fq_codel vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm drm_kms_helper ramoops 
pstore_blk pstore_zone reed_solomon drm efi_pstore fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt msr
parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul psmouse mptspi mpts
csih
[1106.400694]ahci libahci mptbase e1000 scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4 pata_acpi usbhid hid floppy
[1106.407278]CPU:0 PID:2535 Comm:InputThread Tainted:GD5.19.0-50-gener1c#50-Ubuntu
[1106.408458]Hardware name:VMware,Inc.VMware virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform,BI0S6.0011/12/2020
[1106.409642]Call Trace:
[1106.410228]<TASK>
[1106.410786]show_stack+0x52/0x69
[1106.411373]dump_stack_1v1+0x49/0x6d
[1106.411943]dump_stack+0x10/0x18
[1106.412498]__schedule_bug.cold+0x46/0x62
[1106.413053]__schedule+0x473/0x5d0
[1106.413525]？vprintk+0x67/0xh0
[1106.413995]？-printk+0x58/0x81
[1106.414423]do_task_dead+0x44/0x50
[1106.414874]make_task_dead.cold+0x3e/0x94
[1106.415333]rewind_stack_and_make_dead+0x17/0x20
[1106.415808]RIP:0033:0×7f6bcc491340
[1106.416230]Code:Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f6bcc491316.
[1106.416631]RSP:002h:00007f6hbef87db8 EFLAGS:000002820RIG_RAX:00000000000000ca
[1106.417111]RAX:fffffffffffffe0o RBX:000055f5c5d02aa0 RCX:00007f6bcc491340
[1106.417539]RDX:0000000000000002R8I:0000000000000080RDI:000055f5c4fc5360
[1106.417965]RBP:000000000000001aR08:0000000000000000R09:000055f5c4dcf785
[1106.418370]R10:0000000000000000R11:0000000000000282R12:0000000000000001
[1106.418800]R13:00007f6bbef87e1cR14:000055f5c4f649e0R15:00007fffc4c95680
[1106.419215]</TASK>
```

I have frequently encountered this issue recently. It is possible to forcibly shut down, but running for a period of time after restarting will encounter this problem again. How can I solve it